# How do I go about troubleshooting Okta app issues?

Tags: spring-boot, okta

I followed the instructions here:
https://github.com/okta/samples-js-react/tree/master/okta-hosted-login

And here:
https://github.com/okta/samples-java-spring/tree/master/resource-server

...to set up a sample reactjs app authenticating with Okta.

Worked like a charm with my developer Okta account.

But when I tried to use my organisation's Okta configurations, I'm encounter errors while trying to bring up the resource server.

Here are the configurations in my application.yml:

```
okta:
  oauth2:
    issuer: "https://<myOrgName>.okta-emea.com/oauth2/default"
    client-id: "<myClientId>"
    client-secret: "<myClientSecret>"
```

I created a new application in Okta developer console with a Web configuration, which gave me the clientId and clientSecret.

And when I do this:

```
cd resource-server
mvn
```

I see this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project okta-spring-boot-oauth-resource-server: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$JwkTokenStoreConfiguration: 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
```

Any pointers on what I'm missing? How can I troubleshoot what is going wrong? Any logs in Okta?

Answer (score 0):

It happens that we need to enable a paid add-on "API Access Management" to make this work. https://www.okta.com/pricing/?&_ga=2.83722128.789595063.1528210367-1946999837.1524501420#api-access-management